# Regex to match accept-language header

Tags: javascript, regex, http-headers

I am trying to match the following accept-language header field of a http request.

```
var regex = /([^-]*)(?:-([^;]*))?(?:;q=([0-9].[0-9]))?/
"en-us;q=0.8".match(regex) => ["en-us;q=0.8", "en", "us", "0.8"]
"en".match(regex) => ["en", "en", undefined, undefined]
"en;q=0.8".match(regex) => ["en;q=0.8", "en;q=0.8", undefined, undefined]
```

The problem is in the last line. It should imho yield:

```
["en;q=0.8", "en", "0.8", undefined]
```

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. There are tools for handling accept-language headers. If you are using express server I would recommend you try out request-language https://github.com/tinganho/express-request-language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first capturing group matches everything that doesn't contain dashes and stops at a dash `-`. In your last string you have no dash, so it matches the entire string. The other parts of your regexp are optional, so they match nothing.

You can fix it for this particular case by not allowing `;` in your first capturing group:

```
/([^-;]*)(?:-([^;]*))?(?:;q=([0-9]\.[0-9]))?/
```

PS: I also fixed your dot in the last capturing group. It matched any character, now it matches only the `.` character.

Comment: Please be aware that the locale part of the `Accept-Language:` header is required to conform to `/\*|[A-Z]{1,8}(-[A-Z0-9]{1,8})*/i` as per [RFC3066 Section 2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3066#section-2.1). So, your proposed answer answer accepts a wider set of inputs than what is semantically correct.

Comment: @ioquatix Please submit that as an aswer

Answer (score 1):

Since @ioquatix never submitted an answer that better followed [RFC3066 Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3066#section-2.1), I'm posting my version that should align better with the standard:

```
/^((?<primary>\*|([A-Z]{1,8}))((?<!\*)-(?<subtag>[A-Z0-9]{1,8}))?)(;q=(?<quality>1|0|0.[0-9]{1,3}))?$/i
```